# Button to award bounty is visible next to answer that already has a bounty

Tags: support, design, bounty

I offered a bounty on a question, and after a refresh the blue `+100` "button" also appeared below an answer that already got a bounty awarded to it.

> [image: double bounty all the way]

As far as I'm aware an answer can only have a single bounty awarded to it, however I could not find this constraint documented anywhere.

Is that button supposed to show up for an answer that already has a bounty? The lack of margin makes it seem unintentional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An answer can be awarded with multiple bounties, so it's not a bug. Nonetheless, I think that some margin should be added to the award bounty button.

Comment: In that case this question of mine is a duplicate of another I found in the suggestions after posting - I've marked it as such.